# Как взять title из iframe и передать его странице, в которой он загружается?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

На страницы моего сайта выводится в теге iframe другая страница этого же сайта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как взять title страницы, которая расположена в iframe и разместить его значение в title страницы, в которой расположен этот тег iframe (то есть в той, в которой он загружается)? Если я ничего не путаю, в js есть функция postMessage, которая без задержек передают значения между разными документами. Но как это сделать я не знаю. В принципе мне все равно, через что это реализовать (будь то js или php), лишь бы это точно и быстро работало.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, что у нас такой `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="otherPage" src="otherPage.php"></iframe>
```

Можно передать `title` вот так:

```
document.getElementById("otherPage").onload = function() {
  document.title = this.contentDocument.title;
}
```

Comment: У меня вот такой код с передачей меток в url с помощью php: <iframe id="ifr" src="<?php print $url.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>" FRAMEBORDER="0"></iframe> На какую страницу нужно разместить ваш код? Пробовал на ту, в которой расположен iframe, но изменений никаких не было. id естественно менял.

Comment: @Widgin Да, в ту страницу, в которой расположен `iframe`. Если у вас только один `iframe`, То можно использовать `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]` вместо `document.getElementById("otherPage")`.